# Ошибки при запуске make menuconfig при компиляции ядра

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

Обновил ncurses-dev на Ubuntu. Всё успешно. Обновил пакет для утилиты make. Но при попытке запустить menuconfig вылетают ошибки, не пойму в чем проблема. В системе всё апйдетил и апргрейдил, устаревшего ничего нету.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А компилятор (gcc) у вас установлен ?

Comment: Да,было глупо не посмотреть в самую первую строчку ошибки. Всё верно, установил gcc apt-get-ом, но теперь каждый раз просит что-то новое: bison, flex.. Можно ли скачать какую то либу, где всё это хранится ?

Comment: DONE. Установил олдовый флекс,и всё пошло-поехало. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: стопицотмиллионный раз: используйте аккаунт с идентификатором 0 (в unix-подобных операционных системах обычно с этим идентификатором создаётся пользователь с именем root) только для выполнения задач по администрированию системы. это относится к всем способам авторизации: login, xsession, su, sudo, kexec и т.д. и т.п.